# IOS/Objective-C: returning to main thread

Tags: ios, dispatch-async

I think I understand how the following works but would appreciate confirmation.

```
dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
    NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: dataUrl];
    [self fetchData:data];//go to web, get data and store in core data
}
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    //display new data on main thread.
}
```

My question is can I take it for granted that the display on the main thread will not take place until after the conclusion of everything that occurs in the background--no matter how long?

The reason I would appreciate confirmation is that occasionally I am observing some issues with the display.  Want to be sure the display is not trying to access core data when background thread has not finished saving to it.

Comment: that is correct. but what do you mean with 'the display is not...."? How can 'the display' do anything.

Comment: The call to `[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL]` might be doing a network request from the web, depending on where the URL points to. If it's a file url pointing to a file on the local file system, it would simply fetch the data from the local file. If it's a remote url like `http://foo/bar.jpg` then it will SYNCHRONOUSLY fetch the data from a remote server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is not correct. You are attempting to update the UI long before the data is retrieved from the URL.

You need:

```
dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
    NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: dataUrl];
    [self fetchData:data];//go to web, get data and store in core data
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        //display new data on main thread.
    }
}
```

This code also assumes that `fetchData:` is not asynchronous meaning that it doesn't return until the data has been fetched and updated.

Comment: So providing I put the dispatch to the main queue inside the dispatch_asynch, it will wait for fetch data to complete?

Comment: Yes, it's no different than another other method call. But as I said, this only works if the implementation of `fetchData:` doesn't return until the data has been fetched and stored in core data. If its implementation is asynchronous then `fetchData:` will return too soon. The solution will then be to add a completion handler to `fetchData`.

Comment: I'm sensing that you don't understand how async function calls work. An async function returns immediately, before the task is complete.

Comment: @DuncanC Are you responding to me or Arjun?